NullReferenceException when Accessing Identity Services in a Background Job in .NET Core
I'm running into an issue where a recurring background job in my .NET Core application throws a NullReferenceException when accessing UserManager or RoleManager from the ASP.NET Core Identity framework.
The identity tables (AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles, etc.) are properly registered in the DI container, and everything works fine in a regular request pipeline. However, when running this job in the background, it crashes with the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
Inside my background job, I'm using IServiceScopeFactory to create a scope for accessing UserManager, RoleManager, and ApplicationDbContext:
 using (var serviceScope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
 {
     var dbContext = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
     var roleManager = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<ApplicationRole>>();
     var userManager = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();

     var allRoles = await roleManager.Roles.ToListAsync();
     var allUsers = await userManager.Users.ToListAsync();
}


The Identity services are registered properly in Startup.cs.
The UserManager and RoleManager are scoped correctly, and I'm using IServiceScopeFactory to create a new scope in the background job.
Logging shows that the NullReferenceException occurs when accessing identity services inside the job, even though they're registered in the DI container.

Why are UserManager and RoleManager null in the background job, and how can I fix this issue?
Is there something special about how Identity services work in background jobs that I need to configure differently?
.NET Core version: [6]
Identity configuration in Startup.cs is using AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>().

Could you please provide more details how is your program.cs, and the debug information like in which step you got the error and value of allUsers? I cannot reproduce it , I tested with your code and got an inValidOperation error.

why do you use service factory inside the hangfire job when hangfire job does that for you. If you are using Hangfire.AspNetCore packge hangfire does creation of scope for you.  Can you share on how you set up the hangfire ?
